# "Touchmove" event only ever returns "touchstart" coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, touch-event

I am trying to get the circle in the snippet below to follow either a mouse, or a finger on a mobile device. To do this, I have set up a "mousemove" event handler and a "touchmove" event handler. I can't figure out why the "touchmove" event handler is not working correctly. The event handlers are almost identical, but when I log the touchmove coordinates, only the initial coordinates of the touch are recorded.

```js
//Determines if user is on mobile
function mobileTest(){
    var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)");
    return isMobile.matches ? true : false;
}

//  pass in number for top of range non-inclusive
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

class node {
  constructor(x, y, angSpeed){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.angSpeed = angSpeed;
    this.angle = getRandomInt(360);
    this.active = false;
    this.nextActive = false;
  }
  update(rad, angle){
    this.x = context.width/2 + Math.cos(angle) * rad;
    this.y = yCenter + Math.sin(angle) * rad;
    this.angle += this.angSpeed;
  }
  setActive(){
    this.active = true;
  }
  clearActive(){
    this.active = false;
  }
  setNextActive(){
    this.nextActive = true;
  }
  clearNextActive(){
    this.nextActive = false;
  }
}

class coin {
  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.xTwo = 4;
    this.y = y;
    this.initialY = y;
    this.size = 8;
    this.cont = 0;
    this.direction = "down";
  }
  update(){
    this.cont++;
    if(this.cont%75 == 0){
      this.cont = 0;
      if (this.direction == "up"){
        this.direction = "down"
      } else  {
        this.direction = "up";
      }
    }
    if(this.direction == "up"){
      this.y+=.5;
      this.xTwo+=.2;
    } else if(this.direction == "down") {
      this.y-=.5;
      this.xTwo-=.2;
    }

  }
  setActive(){
    this.active = true;
  }
  clearActive(){
    this.active = false;
  }

}

class trackCircle{
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
  }
}

class player{
  constructor() {
    this.x = context.width/2;
    this.y = yCenter - basis/6;
    this.velocity = 10;
    this.mouseX = mouseX;
    this.mouseY = mouseY;
  }
  update(){
    let dx = this.x - mouseX;
    let dy = this.y - mouseY;
    let angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx)
    let xVelocity = this.velocity * Math.cos(angle);
    let yVelocity = this.velocity * Math.sin(angle);
    if ((Math.abs(dx) > 5) || (Math.abs(dy) > 5)){
      if(pointInCircle(mouseX, mouseY, context.width/2, yCenter, basis/3)){
        this.x -= xVelocity;
        this.y -= yVelocity;
      }
    }
    this.mouseX = mouseX;
    this.mouseY = mouseY;

  }
}

function clearActive(){
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
      nodes[i].clearActive();
    }
    nodes[0].setActive();
}

function clearNextActive(){
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
      nodes[i].clearNextActive();
    }
}

function setNextActive(numActive){
  nextPairs = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < numActive; i++){
    let tmp1 = getRandomInt(nodes.length);
    while(tmp1 == 0){
      tmp1 = getRandomInt(nodes.length);
    }
    let tmp2 = tmp1;
    while(tmp1 == tmp2 || tmp2 == 0){
      tmp2 = getRandomInt(nodes.length);
    }
    nextPairs[i] = [tmp1, tmp2,  0];
  }
}

function makeCoins(){
  for(var i = 0; i  < 10; i++){
    var pt_angle = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
    var pt_radius_sq = Math.random() * (basis/3) * (basis/3);
    var pt_x = Math.sqrt(pt_radius_sq) * Math.cos(pt_angle);
    var pt_y = Math.sqrt(pt_radius_sq) * Math.sin(pt_angle);
    coins[i] = new coin((pt_x + context.width/2), (pt_y + yCenter));
  }
}

function setActive(numActive){
  pairs = nextPairs;
}

async function timer(){
  timeleft = 4;
  var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(timeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(downloadTimer);
    clearActive();
    setActive(numActive);
    makeCoins();
    NextTimer();
  } else {


  }
  timeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}

async function NextTimer(){
  nextTimeleft = 4;
  var nextDownloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if(nextTimeleft <= 0){
    clearInterval(nextDownloadTimer);
    clearNextActive()
    setNextActive(numActive);
    timer();
  } else {

  }
  nextTimeleft -= 1;
  }, 1000);
}

//Initialize Canvas
var canvas = document.getElementsByClassName("game");
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName("gameCont");
canvas[0].width = parent[0].offsetWidth;
canvas[0].height = document.body.clientHeight;
let header = document.getElementById("header");
let gameActive = true;
let backgroundColor = "#D0CA96";
let playAreaColor = "#D096B9";
let trackColor = "#96D0AD";
let activeColor = "#969CD0";
let shadowColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.1)'
let r = 0;
var mouseX = 0;
var mouseY = 0;
let timeleft = 5;
let nextTimeleft = 5;
let numActive = 1;
let trackCircles = [];
let nodes = [];
let coins = [];
let pairs = [];
let nextPairs = [];
const context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.width = document.body.clientWidth;
context.height = document.body.clientHeight;
context.fontFamily = "Secular One, sans-serif";

var basis = context.height;
let yCenter = context.height/2 - context.height/10;

//initialize player
player = new player();

//Create track circles
let additive = (basis/3)/10;
let marker = 0;
for(var i = 0; r < (basis/3)+1; i++){
  if (i == 0){
    trackCircles[marker] = new trackCircle(r);
    marker++;
  } else if ( i > 3 ){
    trackCircles[marker] = new trackCircle(r);
    marker++;
  }
  r+=additive;
}

//create nodes
for(var i = 0; i < trackCircles.length; i++){
  nodes[i] = new node((context.width/3 + trackCircles[i].radius), yCenter, (Math.random() * (0.03 - 0.015) + 0.015));
}

// x,y is the point to test
// cx, cy is circle center, and radius is circle radius
function pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, radius) {
  var distancesquared = (x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy);
  return distancesquared <= radius * radius;
}

//Listen for click/touch events
const mouseTracker = {
  mouseListener: function(e) {
    if (event.target.className == "game"){
      let tmpx = e.offsetX;
      let tmpy = e.offsetY;
      if(pointInCircle(tmpx, tmpy, context.width/2, yCenter, basis/3)){
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
      }

    }
  }
}

const touchTracker = {
  touchListener: function(event){
      var touch = event.touches[0];
      if (event.target.className == "game"){
        let tmpx = touch.offsetX;
        let tmpy = touch.offsetY;
        if(pointInCircle(tmpx, tmpy, context.width/2, yCenter, basis/3)){
          e.preventDefault(); // we don't want to scroll
          mouseX = touch.offsetX;
          mouseY = touch.offsetY;
        }

      }
  }
}

//Main game loop logic
const loop = function () {

  // Creates the backdrop for each frame
  context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, context.width, context.height); // x, y, width, height

  //create play area and backdground
  for (var i = 15; i >= 0; i--){
    context.beginPath()
    if (i%2 == 0){
      context.fillStyle = playAreaColor;
    } else{
      context.fillStyle = trackColor;
    }
    context.arc(context.width/2, yCenter + (i*30), basis/3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath()

  }
  context.fillStyle = playAreaColor;
  context.arc(context.width/2, yCenter, basis/3, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();


  //Create track circles
  for(var i = 0; i < trackCircles.length; i++){
    context.beginPath()
    context.arc(context.width/2, yCenter, trackCircles[i].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    if((trackCircles.length - 1) == i){
      context.strokeStyle = activeColor;
      context.lineWidth = 6;
      context.setLineDash([]);
    } else {
      context.setLineDash([5, 15]);
      context.strokeStyle = trackColor;
      context.lineWidth = 3;
    }
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath()
  }

  // create coins
  for(var i = 0; i < coins.length; i++){
    coins[i].update();

    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = shadowColor;
    context.ellipse(coins[i].x, coins[i].initialY, Math.abs(coins[i].xTwo) + 4, 4, 0, 1, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
    context.closePath();
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "white";
    context.arc(coins[i].x, coins[i].y, coins[i].size, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    context.fill();
  }

  //draw player
  player.update();
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = "white";
  //context.fillRect(player.x - 15, player.y - 15, 30, 30);
  context.arc(player.x, player.y, 13, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
  context.stroke()
  context.closePath();

  //draw lines  from center to active nodes
  for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j <  pairs[i].length; j++){
      context.beginPath();
      //context.moveTo(nodes[pairs[i][0]].x, nodes[pairs[i][0]].y);
      context.moveTo(nodes[0].x, nodes[0].y);
      context.lineTo(nodes[pairs[i][j]].x, nodes[pairs[i][j]].y);
      context.strokeStyle = activeColor;
      context.lineWidth = 6;
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
    }
  }

  //draw nodes
  //active
  for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++){
    nodes[pairs[i][0]].setActive();
    nodes[pairs[i][1]].setActive();
    nodes[pairs[i][2]].setActive();
  }
  //nextActive
  for(var i = 0; i < nextPairs.length; i++){
    nodes[nextPairs[i][0]].setNextActive();
    nodes[nextPairs[i][1]].setNextActive();
    nodes[nextPairs[i][2]].setNextActive();
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    nodes[i].update(trackCircles[i].radius, nodes[i].angle)
    if (nodes[i].active == true || nodes[i].nextActive == true){
      context.beginPath()
      context.arc(nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      context.fillStyle = trackColor;
      context.fill();
      context.closePath()
      if(nodes[i].active == true){
        context.beginPath()
        context.arc(nodes[i].x, nodes[i].y, 12, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        context.strokeStyle = activeColor;
        context.lineWidth = 6;
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath()
      }
    }
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);

};

window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseTracker.mouseListener, false);
window.addEventListener("touchmove", touchTracker.touchListener, { passive: false});

// clicks anywhere on  the screen
window.onclick = function(event) {

}

setNextActive(numActive);
setActive(numActive);
timer(timeleft);
// Start animation loop
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900i&display=swap");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Righteous&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Coiny&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Modak&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka+One&family=Modak&display=swap');

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 5vw;
    letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:
                        1px 1px #4EB1D9,
                        2px 2px #000000;
}

footer {
  position: static;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  height: 2.5rem;
  /*position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;   */         /* Footer height */
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  block-size: 100%;
  min-height:100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: 'Coiny', sans-serif;
}

img {
  float: center;
  width: 30vw;
  height: 25vw;
  object-fit: scale-down;
}

button {
  float: center;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.gameCont{
  display: flex;
  position: relative,
  float: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.game{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
  float: center;
  block-size: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #D0CA96;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header a {
  left: 50%;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: #969CD0;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
  /*-webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
  color: white;*/
  text-shadow:
            0px 0px #969CD0,
            2px 2px #96D0AD,
                        4px 4px #969CD0,
            6px 6px #96D0AD,
            8px 8px #969CD0,
            10px 10px #96D0AD,
                        12px 12px #969CD0,
            14px 14px #96D0AD;
}

.header button {
  float: left;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
/* Style the logo link (notice that we set the same value of line-height and font-size to prevent the header to increase when the font gets bigger */
.header v.logo {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Change the background color on mouse-over */
.header button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Style the active/current link*/
.header button.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

/* Float the link section to the right */
.header-right {
  float: right;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: block; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10% auto; /* 10% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  width: 75%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  text-align: center;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*LeaderBoard Table Defs */
.tableFixHeadLB {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 60vh;
}
.tableFixHeadLB thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
/*Table Defs */
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 30vh;
}
.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed ;
  width: 100%;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 1vh 1vh;
  align-items: center;
}
th {
  background: #eee;
}
.tableFixHead,
.tableFixHead td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHead th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB,
.tableFixHeadLB td {
  box-shadow: inset 1px -1px #000;
}
.tableFixHeadLB th {
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px #000, 0 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Retina</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:900i&display=swap" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header" id="header">
    <br><br>
    <a href="#default" class="logo">Retina</a>
    <div class="header-right">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gameCont">
    <canvas class="game"></canvas>
  </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
      crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://download.playfab.com/PlayFabClientApi.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem ain't related to the `touchmove` listener per se. The issue is caused by the data this event actually returns. As you said, your event handlers are almost identical - and that's the crux of the matter. A touchmove event does not return `offsetX` and `offsetY` properties.

To make it behave like the mousemove listener you have to use the e.g. `clientX` and `clientY` properties. Those alone don't return the correct position though as it depends on the position of the parent HTML element.

Try modifying your listener like this:

```
const touchTracker = {
    touchListener: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var touch = event.touches[0];
        if (event.target.className == "game") {
            let tmpx = touch.clientX - document.getElementsByClassName("game")[0].getBoundingClientRect().x;
            let tmpy = touch.clientY - document.getElementsByClassName("game")[0].getBoundingClientRect().y;
            if (pointInCircle(tmpx, tmpy, context.width / 2, yCenter, basis / 3)) {
                event.preventDefault(); // we don't want to scroll
                mouseX = tmpx;
                mouseY = tmpy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```